# Copy file from remote server terminal to local system

Tags: unix, remote-connection

I use putty on Vista to connect to remote UNIX shell. But I want to copy files from that remote server to my local Vista system. How to do that??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pscp or psftp, both of which are parts of the PuTTY suite.

Comment: Instructions here: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html

Answer (score 3):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is a GUI interface to the scp and sftp protocols mentioned by CarlF.  It can use PuTTY's authentication keys, including the Pageant key server, if you're using that.  Otherwise, though, it doesn't depend on any other programs, including the rest of PuTTY.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot SCP a file to your local machine from within a PuTTY session, as you're not in the shell of your Windows machine, but rather in the shell of the remote machine.

The [PuTTY suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) does however come with a SCP client called PSCP. This means you can use PSCP from your normal Windows Command Prompt to transfer files over SCP.

For more information on how to do this, see [the manual of PSCP](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter5.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cygwin ( http://www.cygwin.com ) which will allow you to run Linux like commands in Windows.  I routinely use this tool to run ssh, scp and widely used Linux commands.  If/when you install cygwin, make sure to install the network group, which includes the ssh, scp.